# Twitter Bootstrap Modal example does not work for me

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This is the code I intend do run: [the second example of Modals](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

But even on jsfiddle it didn't work: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cKH8X/)

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for asking but the twitter bootstrap nowhere online references a modal. The link you provided is not working, was modal pulled from the latest bootstrap release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a reference to `bootstrap.js` or`bootstrap.min.js` which you need in addition to the `bootstrap.min.css` file that you have already referenced.

See this updated working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cKH8X/2/